# monacaバックエンドの「プッシュ通知プロジェクトID」はコード上から取得できますか？

Tags: monaca, push-notification

アプリ内で(Monacaバックエンドの)「プッシュ通知プロジェクトID」を取得する事は出来ないでしょうか？

現在、Monacaを利用してプッシュ通知を受信するアプリを作成しています。
プッシュ通知は、monacaのマネイジメントAPIを有効にし、外部サーバーからプッシュ通知が行えるようにして、アプリ側で通知を受信する事まで確認できました。

外部サーバー側では、「プッシュ通知プロジェクトID」をハードコーディングしているのですが、アプリ固有の情報は、なるべく動的にアプリ側から取得して、サーバー側のプッシュ通知送信処理を汎用的にしたいと思っています。

アプリ側で「プッシュ通知プロジェクトID」が取得できれば、アプリ起動時のタイミングなどでサーバーへ送信する事ができるのですが、そういう事を知っている方が入れば情報を教えてもらえないでしょうか。

もしくは、アプリ側でアプリを識別できるID(Androidで言えばパッケージ名)が取得できれば、サーバー側では「プッシュ通知プロジェクトID」をDBなどに保持しておき、IDをキーに取得出来るのですが、パッケージ名の取得方法も見当たりませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

Monacaチームに問い合わせたところ、今のところ「プッシュ通知プロジェクトID」を動的に取得するようなAPIは無いということです。user8358さんがやっているようにハードコーディングするしかないようです。